# LMA (License Management App) problem in sfLma.updateCustomerLicense

Tags: partner-wsdl, lma

We are getting this error when trying to increase licensed seats through the "Modify License" button:

> sfLma.updateCustomerLicense: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.UnexpectedException: Element
>   {urn:partner.soap.sforce.com}returnAPIPerformanceInfo invalid at this
>   location (System Code)

Suspect it may be a Summer '16 versioning bug (as the org the LMA is installed into is Summer '16). I've created a support request but would appreciate any insight or work-arounds to speed the fixing process up.

(We are using version 1.19.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for Salesforce paid support who just replied:

> They've identified this as a known issue and are working to resolve
>   this. In the meantime, if you could provide us with the licenses that
>   need updating with what needs to be updated, we can do that for you in
>   the back-end until this gets fixed.

And a day later:

> I heard from Tier 3 that the fix went in yesterday. You should be able
>   to make the changes yourself now without Tier 3's intervention.